# Why this String is not eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, string

The following code creates one array and one string object. How many references to those objects exist after the code executes? Is either object eligible for garbage collection?

```
...
String[] students = new String[10];
String studentName = "Peter Parker";
students[0] = studentName;
studentName = null;
...
```

My answer was studentName is eligible for garbage Collection.But the answer given was both are not eligible.What I thought was students[0] refers to the String "Peter Parker" and studentName also does the same.Now that studentName refers to null, students[0] remains referring to "Peter Parker" ( I checked this by printing it out).The explanation given was students[0] is still referring to studentName so studentName is also not eligible for garbage Collection.But I'm not understanding this that since studentName now refers to null and students[0] refers to "Peter Parker".Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Can you give a link to the place that says that it refers to `studentName` rather than the string `"Peter Parker"`?

Comment: No string reference  is eligible for garbage collection

Comment: I think you should change the title of this post to something that will help future visitors, search engines to help find this post.

Comment: So here is the link for the explanation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/objects-answers.html) The last sentence says the object studentName is also not eligible , so this is very confusing as studentName is a reference variable and it refers to null now.

Answer (score 6):

Before `studentName = null;` is executed, `studentName` and `students[0]` both hold references to the same `String` object (whose value is `"Peter Parker"`). When you assign `null` to `studentName`, `students[0]` still refers to that object, so it can't be garbage collected.

Java doesn't garbage collect reference variables, it garbage collects the objects that were referenced by these variables once there are no more references to them.

Answer (score 3):

Here String object is created with `"Peter Parker"` and `studentName` is
 just referring it. Java will garbage collecting those object who are
 lost and have no reference , here you are confused with reference
 `studentName`. by assigning `null` to `studentName` you are just removing
 one reference of `"Peter Parker"`; but it still refer by array element ,
 so it will not garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

### How many objects do you have?

You have **two** objects:

- The string `"Peter Parker"`
- An array of strings.

### How many references are/were there to those objects?

There were **three** references:

- The variable `studentName` is referencing the string object.
- The variable `students` is referencing the array object.
- The first position of the array object, `students[0]` is also referencing the string object.

### How many references to those objects exist after the code executes?

After executing this line:

```
studentName = null;
```

Only the first of the three references has been deleted. We still have **two** references left.

### Is either object eligible for garbage collection?

**No**, because:

- The array object is still referenced by the `students` variable.
- The string object `"Peter parker"` is still referenced by the first position of the array object, `students[0]`.

Since both objects are still referenced somewhere, none of them are eligible for garbage collection.

---

*PS: I've used generic "string" and "array" terms for the objects on purpose, so it's easier to mentally dissociate them from the actual String and String[] variables in the code.*